# discord.py | on_member_update

Tags: python, discord.py

я не знаю почему, но событие on_member_update вызывается **только** когда изменяется профиль бота, если изменится профиль обычного пользователя, то событие не вызывается.
Во мой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connect!")
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print("Before roles:")
    for x in before.roles:
        print(x)
    print("After roles:")
    for x in after.roles:
        print(x)
bot.run("gg")
```

Список ролей выводится только когда изменяется профиль бота, а на профили обычных пользователей ему всё равно.
Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой код. Он выполняет ту же задачу которую ты хотел и так же есть и еще несколько фич в нём.
Не забудь добавить библиотеку asyncio

```
@Bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.roles != after.roles:
        global cooldown
        if before in cooldown:
            return
        cooldown.append(before)
        await asyncio.sleep(5) #5 секунд cooldown для обработки действия
        cooldown.remove(before)
        channel = Bot.get_channel(827986763606786099) #ID канала с логами, а именно куда должны появлятся сообщения об изменениях ролях.
        emb = discord.Embed(description=f'**Обновление ролей пользователя -  {before.mention}**', colour=discord.Color.orange())
        emb.add_field(name='Роли до', value=" ".join([r.mention for r in before.roles][1:]), inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name='Роли после', value=" ".join([r.mention for r in after.roles][1:]), inline=False)
        changed_roles = []
        for role in before.roles:
            if role in after.roles:
                pass
            else:
                changed_roles.append(role)

        for role in after.roles:
            if role in before.roles:
                pass
            else:
                if role in changed_roles:
                    pass
                else:
                    changed_roles.append(role)

        text = ""
        blacklist=[797920206407598098,817750571330961410,797916381621256202] #здесь находятся роли на которые бот не должен реагировать.
        for role in changed_roles:
            if role.id in blacklist:
                return
            text = text + role.mention + " "
        emb.add_field(name="Изменённые роли", value=text, inline=False)
        async for event in before.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update):
            if getattr(event.target, "id", None) != before.id:
                continue
            emb.add_field(name="Модератор", value=f"{event.user} \n**ID**: {event.user.id}")
            break
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
```